# Google Script doPost accept from a single URL only

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, google-apps-script

Is there a way that once request received from a specific URL then the doPost will trigger and if incorrect URL will send error response back?

Comment: If don't use the correct url then nothing happens because there is no trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Only the url query parameters sent from the client are accessible server side. The `origin` header is not accessible server side. So, if you `POST` to

```
https://script.google.com/[DEPLOYMENT_UD]/exec/?secret=udggurahtdlDCkyyrxkymjgugsutdoyfitsittjrsktdwqFusuuwUrsDdfgUTT
```

from client,  The `secret` is accessible from `doPost(e)` in `e.parameter.secret` and you may be able to  verify it, but  you cannot check  the Host sending the request.

Comment: Hi TheMaster, thanks for the guidance. I will try what you have suggestion. :)

Comment: Hi TheMaster, I have tried and it seem the if else I have added in my google script isn't working as expected. I hope you can enlighten me more the updated post code?

Comment: @CodeNerd85 Kindly post a new question instead. Revert your edits to this question. This site preserves a Q/A format and not a forum style format.

Comment: Thank you for your earlier guidance. Reverted my earlier edit to my question also.